# Java - Calling private functions of a class from mock of public function in the class

Tags: java, mocking

I am looking for a way to test the data in a class that processes the data and then uploads the data in a manner as clean and portable as possible. So I would like to not resort to making public get functions, to avoid anything being able to reach this data. To keep it portable, I would like to avoid using a test database, so that these tests can be ran in any situation.

```
Class Foo {     
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private DBSaver dbSaver;

    public Foo(DBSaver dbSaver) {       
        this.dbSaver = dbSaver;
    }

    public void processData() {           
        processData();
        saveToDB();
    }

    private void workNumbers() {     
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = a + b;
    }

    private void saveToDB() {           
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(a); list.add(b); list.add(c);
        dbSaver.save(list);
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
class FooTest {       
    @Mock
    DBSaver dbSaver;
    @Mock
    Foo foo;

    @Test
    private void test() {when(dbSaver.save(any(ArrayList<>.class))).then(returnsFirstArg());
        foo = new Foo(dbSaver);
        Mockito.doThrow(new Exception() {
                //Now I would like to get a, b and c so I can ensure that they have the proper values.
            }
            ).when(foo).processData();
    }
}
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/rAhpYqVc) is a pastebin version of the code]().

workNumbers() will be executed as normal, and since the save() function has been mocked to do nothing, that code won't do anything too serious.

I would like to ask if there is a way to now get the a, b and c values back in list form, through mocking an exception being thrown. The problem is accessing the private values in Foo through the mocked instance in FooTest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting unit testing with mocking wrong. There is no point in having this:

```
@Mock
Foo foo;
```

Foo is your "class under test". You do **not** want to mock that. If at all, you might want to create a *spy* here, in order to do *[partial mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others)*.

In your case, you don't need to **access** those private fields. You see, the key point is that your code will call:

```
dbSaver.save(list);
```

at some point. Meaning: you can use Mockitoy to **verify** that a specific list is passed when `save()` is called on that **mocked** dbSaver object.

That is the whole point: you have that mocked dbSaver instance, so you are in *total* control what happens there. As said, you can *verify* that its methods are called with a specific argument; or you can even use an ArgumentCaptor in order to **access** the list passed to that method call.

And then you simply ensure that the list contains the *expected* content (which would be those three values from your class under test!). See 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555472/mockito-verify-method-arguments) for examples how to do that.

Finally: especially that "exception" part is really wrong. There is no need to generate an exception here. You simply push a mocked dbSaver into an instance of Foo, you call a method on that Foo instance; and then you check for the expected results. That's it; anything else is (useless) over-complication of things.