# How to verify a line in mockito java which has function1().function2().function3();

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, junit4

Hi i am new to Junit & Mockito.
I have code like this:

```
public class ABCCheckout implements Checkout
{
@Resource
public PrimeConfigService primeConfigService;
/* PrimeConfigService getter & setters  */
@Override
public String getBlackOutDays()
{
    return getPrimeConfigService().findPrimeConfigByUid(RDD_ISA).get(0).getValue();
}
}
```

I want to verify that this line is called:

```
return getPrimeConfigService().findPrimeConfigByUid(RDD_ISA).get(0).getValue();
```

& `findPrimeConfigByUid(RDD_ISA)` returns a ArrayList of type ProductModel

So how does i achieve it in my `ABCCheckoutTest` 
where i have code like this

```
@UnitTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ABCheckoutTest{
@InjectMocks
private ABCCheckout aBCCheckout;

@Before
    public void setUp()
    {//what should go here//}

    @Test
    public void testGetBlackOutDays()
    {//what should go here//}

}
```

Comment: Inject a mock `PrimeConfigService` into `ABCCheckout`, then you can [verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555472/mockito-verify-method-arguments) those methods of `PrimeConfigService` were invoked.  For the builder pattern, the [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901368/mockito-verify-order-sequence-of-method-calls) of the method invocations probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't mock every possible class and method. All you need to mock here is the service PrimeConfigService's findPrimeConfigByUid method. And you should make it return a real list containing a real ProductModel.