# JUnit to test how object changes mid process along with final assertions

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, pitest

I have a private method which is used by multiple processes and I'm writing unit test for a public method, during pitest a mutation which removes call to a line survives so in order to fix it(without telling test to ignore that mutation) I want to check that object is updated with certain value in middle of process and another value at the end of process. Is it possible?

```java
public class MyClass {

    public List<Mango> publicMethod() {
    List<Mango> mangos = apiCall();
        privateMethod1(mangos);
        privateMethod2(mangos);
        return mangos;
    }

    private void privateMethod1(List<Mango> mangos) {
        mangos.forEach(mango -> {
            if(mango.getName("indigenous") {
                mango.setAmount(100);
                mango.setQuantity(10);
            }
        });
    }

     private void privateMethod2(List<Mango> mangos) {
        mangos.forEach(mango -> {
            if(mango.getName("indigenous") {
                mango.setAmount(50);
            }
        }
    });   
}
```

In unit test for publicMethod(), removed call to mango.setAmount(100); survives as it gets updated again in privateMethod2 but privateMethod1 is used by multiple processes so it should not be updated. In actual scenario there are multiple things happening in those methods but to explain issue I'm using simple set method to an object. In place of mango.setAmount(100); in actual code there is a private method which will update some values of the object.

To make pitest not to ignore that line I tried to use Mockito.verify() to check that private method is being called twice, but mokito doesn't allow us to verify private methods.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to test the behaviour of the `privateMethod1()`, without have the `privateMethod2()`impact the result ?

Comment: I want to verify mango.setAmount(100) happened before mango.setAmount(50). I'm able to assert amount 50 since it is present in output but not amount 100.

Comment: Your unit test should not be concerns about how the public method are doing their things. They should only be concern with the input and the output of those method. Knowing that, it's quite hard to create a test that will assert only one part of the method.

What you could do, though, is to use a mock and assert the `setAmount` was called twice, and assert the parameters. I havn't done Java in a long time, so i can't give you a concret exempe, but you can look at this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/57281503/5784924

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't be concerned with the behavior of the private methods, as the unit tests would only be concerned with the input/output of the public method.
2. If you really need to achieve this, you could try to create a spy of `Mango` object (`Mango mango = Mockito.spy(Mango.class)`) and check that the setters were called as you expected them: `verify(mango).setAmount(100)` and `verify(mango).setAmount(50)`